# Matching more than one Query String with RewriteCond

Tags: apache-2.2, rewritecond

I have the following configuration in an Apache configuration file for a CGI script:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/var/log/syslog-ng/JBoss.*$
RewriteRule ^/cgi-bin/(.*)$ /secure-cgi-bin/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

The idea being that if someone uses the CGI script to view a path other than ones beginning `/var/log/syslog-ng/JBoss`, they should be redirected through a secured CGI script instead.

I would now like to change the `RewriteCond` so that a second path can also be viewed without going through the secure CGI. This second path is `/var/log/syslog-ng/Tomcat`.

How do I go about making this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple lines and [OR] flag like samarudge told you, but since you only have slightly different paths, here's a reminder: ReWriteCond/Rule supports regular expressions, so format like this is possible, too:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/var/log/syslog-ng/(JBoss|Tomcat).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to chain multiple RewriteCond with the [OR] flag

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/var/log/syslog-ng/JBoss.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/var/log/syslog-ng/Tomcat.*$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^/cgi-bin/(.*)$ /secure-cgi-bin/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```